# Terraform generate lambda functions zip package and update if changes to package

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I'm working on a small piece of work, which requires generating multiple lambda zip packages if any handler.py changes and updating corresponding lambda functions,
the problem I'm facing, I used null_resource triggers to watch all the handler.py and execute my zip generator as provisioner "local-exec", and resource aws_lambda_function source_code_hash to pick up zip update.

this solution tries to update all lambda functions regardless of 1 handler change.

terraform code:

```
variable "lambda_functions_name" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["functions1", "functions2", "functions3", "functions4", "functions5"]
}

resource "null_resource" "lambda_functions_zip" {
  for_each = toset(var.lambda_functions_name)
  triggers = {
    function_name_hash = filesha256("${path.root}/../../lambda_code/${each.key}/handler.py")
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "chmod u+x ./generate_lambda_zip_packages.sh && ./generate_lambda_zip_packages.sh ../terraform/modules/lambda/code ${each.key}"
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    working_dir = "${path.root}/../../"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_functions" {
  for_each      = toset(var.lambda_functions_name)
  function_name = each.value
  description   = "Lambda function for ${each.value}"
  handler       = "lambda_code/${each.value}/handler.handler"
  runtime       = "python3.9"
  timeout       = 15
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_functions_roles[each.key].arn
  filename      = "${path.module}/code/${each.value}.zip"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("${path.module}/code/${each.value}.zip")
}
```

I'm looking to only update the lambda function which the handler changed.

Comment: So you have 5 functions and you want to only update one if its handler changes?